# How to ditribute my Unix application?

Tags: python, unix, package, installation

I created a command-line python tool for Unix systems.

I want my script to be executed from anywhere just like any Unix command. One solution is to make my script executable and move it to /usr/bin.

But the script works with external files, and I guess moving all these files with my script in /usr/bin is a bad habit, as it will be hard to delete them one by one in the future.

Where should I put the directory of my application ? How to add the main script to the PATH, to execute it from anywhere ?

I would like then to create a package that could move my files in the right place, and delete them in the case the user wants to uninstall my application.
I don't know how to do this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There are many way of distributing a Linux application.
It will depend on the distribution you are using, since they do not all use the same **package manager**. For example, you would create a .deb package for Debian, Ubuntu and there derivatives, an Arch package for Archlinux, etc...
You could then share the package with anyone to let them install your tool.

However, since your tool is in written in Python, you can also make a python package. You could then upload it to the [Python Package Index](https://pypi.python.org/pypi) to let anyone install it using python's pip package manager.

To create a python package, you will need to create a file called setup.py, and, from it, to call the setup method from the setuptool packages.
You will probably want to read the python documentation about writing such a script: https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html
You may especially be interested by this sections:

- [Including Data Files](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#including-data-files)
- [Automatic Script Creation](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation)

If you do things correctly, setuptools will take care of installing your script and its files somewhere in the PATH so it can be executed from the command line.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I will be using a python package.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [setuptools](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html) to distribute your application, creating a `setup.py` file to configure its setup and installation.

Binaries can be delivered using the [console_scripts](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation) option, while data files can be delivered using either [package_data](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#including-data-files).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will take a look at these !